# Use JSON row-formatting for my list to give additional rows a different color. But the color is not correct

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I use this JSON code below to give additional rows a different color.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(@rowIndex % 2 == 0,'ms-bgColor-themeLighter ms-bgColor-themeLight--hover','')"
}
```

In the code I used `ms-bgcolor-themeLighter` and `ms-bgColor-ThemeLight--hover`.

Which are these colors:

[image]

But I get purple instead of blue:

[image]

Why is that happening and how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint default theme or any custom theme? If SharePoint default theme, can you share the name of theme you are using?